# Compiling C++: undefined reference

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, compiler-errors, g++

I'm pretty new to C++ and I'm trying to compile [my code](https://github.com/derekchiang/libgsc).  The command I'm using is `g++ -o main --std=c++11 main.cpp channel.cpp`.  However I'm getting the following error message:

```
/tmp/ccLuJs81.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `gsc::Channel<int>::Channel()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `gsc::Channel<int>::put(int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4e): undefined reference to `gsc::Channel<int>::get(bool)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please include the relevant code *here*. Don't send people chasing across the internet for information you should have provided, if you want them to help you.

Comment: Okay, so I don't know enough about g++ so your command line I can't help you with.  I can say that it's clear it's not finding your class function definitions.  So is everything declared and defined correctly?  It could be a linker error or something in your code, but you haven't posted it.

Comment: I don't have time to write out a full answer right now, so here's a comment instead: the problem is that you're defining template functions in the .cpp file. Template definitions must be visible at the site where they're instantiated, which usually means they should be defined in headers. As it is, the only place where the compiler knows that it needs to instantiate the `Channel>` template for ints is in main.cpp. But the only place where it knows *how* to instantiate it for `int` is in channel.cpp.

Comment: It looks like you have a template class `gsc::Channel` which declares a couple of members `Channel`, `put`, `get` whose definition is not visible from main.cpp. Did you put template definitions in a source file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems you declared a template in a header and defined it in a C++ file. This won't work. If you don't define your template in a header, you need to explicitly instantiate it in your C++ file, e.g. ,using

```
template class gcs::Channel<int>;
```

after the definition of all the methods.